# Swift 4 methods chaining

Tags: swift4

There is a problem with Swift 4 methods chaining in my opinion or I'm totally missing something. For example the following code works perfect:

```
class test {
    let id = 10
}

var dict: [Int: test] = [10: test()]

let filtered = dict.filter({ $0.value.id > 10 })
let sorted = filtered.sorted(by: {$0.value.id > $1.value.id })
```

Unfortunately this is not working ...

```
let filteredAndSorted = dict.filter({ $0.value.id > 10 }).sorted(by: {$0.value.id > $1.value.id })
```

What am I missing ... the error is: Ambiguous use of 'filter'

Comment: Did it work differently before ?

Comment: Yes, it worked like this: `let filteredAndSorted = dict.filter({ $0.1.id > 10 }).sorted(by: {$0.1.id > $1.1.id })`

Comment: It is indeed surprising that there is a difference between not chaining or chaining those methods.

Comment: Tell me about it ;-)

Comment: To fix the ambiguity you can add `(dict.filter({ $0.value.id > 10 }) as Dictionary).sorted`...

Comment: Yes indeed it fixes it ... this can't be real ... Please add this as an answer so I can accept it ;-)

Comment: I did it ! :) I will probably make a bug report, this is strange !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the ambiguity you can add :
`(dict.filter({ $0.value.id > 10 }) as Dictionary).sorted`...

Comment: (dict.filter({ $0.value.id > 10 }) as Array).sorted ...  or Array((dict.filter({ $0.value.id > 10 })).sorted ... should work too :-). This is most likely, why the compiler is not able to decide ...

Comment: OFFTOPIC: @Trevör Anne Denise. Can you please look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394748/xcode-9-compiled-app-with-unusual-behaviour)