# Xcode 9 compiled app with unusual behaviour

Tags: xcode9

I'm failing in creating a simple macSO app with Xcode 9 because of a very ... and I mean very strange behaviour. I have two views with simple layers to draw different background colours. Like this:
[image]
When I run the app, without changing anything, after (usually) the third run in a row, the views disappear ... literally. And the window looks like this:
[image]
Here is a test project:

https://github.com/ivailon/test13

Furthermore - if I start executing the already build app, again the views sometimes disappear. Can anyone give even a clue of a reasonable explanation why this is happening ...

Comment: Do you mean that when you hit the "stop" button and hit "run" again the app doesn't look the same as the previous launch ?

Comment: Exactly ... try it  with the example ... Even if you go to the already compiled app - not every time the app looks the same ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that not every time the view's layer is initialised before the call of:

> func viewDidLoad()
>
> **Description**
> Called after the view controller’s view has been loaded into memory.

To fix this one should initialise the layer later or create its own CALayer object and setup the view with it, like this:

```
let layer = CALayer()
layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.orange.cgColor
view1.layer = layer
view1.wantsLayer = true
```

The project has been updated at [GitHub](https://github.com/ivailon/test13) to show the difference.